# What is the main difference between byte addressable and bit addressable?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, cpu-architecture, 8051

I'm learning 8051, and find it's hard to understand [byte addressable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_addressing) and [bit addressable](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_bitaddrobj.htm).

[image: a addressable SPF]

Comment: there is at least one 8051 in the computer you wrote that from if not more, there are several in each server this website lives on, being royalty free and several chip vendors having their own core they have been using for ever, it is still widely used, sure maybe a tenth to a twentieth the number of arm cores you experience today, but it is still a very widely used core buried in things in a way that you normally might not know.

Comment: please post the question at SO and not use links, copy and paste or re-type as needed.

Comment: @old_timer very useful information!! didn't know this at all.

Comment: @old_timer: That is not a 8051, but an 8048, if you refer to the keyboard controller. And that is not active for native USB keybnoard&mouse..

Comment: nope, not talking about keyboards although keyboards and mice have used 8051s as well.  any time you have some state machine or init that is complicated enough that you dont want to risk a pure state machine you dump an 8051 or maybe a z80 into the design and have the board designers connect a flash that contains the firmware.  very popular with networking components.  so some laptop level and other networking phys, etc will have them but certainly a fair amount of the server grade stuff contains them.

Comment: and many of those vendors dont tell you that, they just give you binary blobs you have to either download on boot or program into a spi flash on the board.  Point being the 8051 in particular is still alive and well.  If you want a core that performs and dont mind royalties, you go to arm. you want a core that you dont pay royalties for for some reason 8051 and z80 and some others are on the list (even though I would argue they are not yet royalty free, I would go with a pdp-11/lsi-11 myself if it were up to me)

Comment: like the PIC you can still buy 8051 chips as well.

Comment: over 1000 hits at mouser.  maxim which consumed dallas which was the big name in 8051s for a while, still makes them as well as other names, geez microchip makes one/some, must have been an acquisition...

Comment: @old_timer: I did not refer to the MCU in the keyboard, buit the PS/2 controller in the PC. Chances are good a modern PC does not have an 8051 anymore, but some ARM or a small 8 or 16 bit MCU. There is not only 8051 vs. ARM, e.g. Maxim has its own architecture as have many others. That does not mean there are still a lot of devices with 8051, e.g. USB-hubs or USB-HDD controllers.

Comment: @Lundin 8051 is fun.  Don't knock it.  And it's worth knowing just as a counterpoint to a lot of modern design practice.

Comment: @old_timer thanks, your words helps me a lot

Comment: I think a number of them are worth knowing, there is a pdp11 backend being maintained for gcc right now and you can use the simh simulator with it.  pdp11 and a clear ripoff the msp430 are great instruction sets to learn.  the PIC has other bad taste things, but is a very clean minimal instruction set (like the msp430), the 8051 and 6502, would recommend those first before even mentioning x86 if even bothering with x86.   and then mips for its educational value and lastly arm variations as that is what drives the world right now.  all have educational value and can use simulators...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not really using the terms right, byte addressable is what we are used to an address represents a unique byte in memory or the memory space.  Bit addressable would mean that each bit in the memory space has a unique address, which is not the case.  they are just showing you how to make some macros/variables that can access individual bits, is not an 8051 thing, but a generic programming thing and specifically implemented in C using variable types or keywords (or just macros) for their compiler.

What they are telling you is they have this sbit declaration which unless it is just a macro is clearly not a C standard declaration.  But you can do the same things without.  it is just bit manipulation that they are doing for you.  Normally to set bit 5 you would do something like

```
variable |= (1<<5);
```

to clear bit 5

```
variable&=~(1<<5);
```

and you can certainly make macros from that to make it more generic.  What they have done for this compiler is allow you to declare a variable that is a single bit in some other variable and then that bit sized variable you can set to a one or zero.

Comment: So maybe in this case every bit has it own address(register), and the byte is just a parallel address(register) like other bits?

Answer (score 1):

A type of hardware architecture that supports unique access to individual bytes of data.

For example, let us assume a number 0x1234 (0001001000110100). When storing the numbers on a system which is byte addressable, the first byte of the data (00010010) gets a unique address to the second byte (00110100), i.e each byte aligned in the memory will be uniquely addressable. You could manipulate the content only in chunks of 8bits.

However in case of micro-controller registers were data is stored, if you could manipulate its content bit by bit it’s called bit addressable.